# Causation between two variables

Tags: correlation

I was wondering if there is no well designed experiment how can the case be made
for causation between two associated variables?

Comment: Better to ask on Cross Validated, maybe.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a math question.  In mathematics there is no "causation".  It should be asked in a physics or general science forum.